# Reducing line spacing in sidepar [memoir]

Tags: memoir, line-spacing, sidenotes

I'd like to *reduce* the line spacing in sidepar. A slight reduction could result in a better placement of my sidenotes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\normalfont \RaggedRight \footnotesize   }

\sideparmargin{outer} 


\begin{document}


\sidepar{\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if this gives what you asking for:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\RaggedRight\footnotesize}% <-- corrected
\sideparmargin{outer}

\begin{document}
\sidepar{\begin{Spacing}{0.8} \lipsum[2] \end{Spacing}}% <-- added Spacing from Memoir
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
From your comment follows, that you need solution solved in preamble. This is is possible with redefinition of  `\sidepar` as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\RaggedRight\footnotesize}%
\sideparmargin{outer}

\let\oldsidepar\sidepar  % < ---- definition of \oldsidepar
\renewcommand\sidepar[1]{% < -- redefinition of \sidepar
    \leavevmode
    \oldsidepar{\RaggedRight\footnotesize
    \begin{Spacing}{0.8}#1%
    \end{Spacing}%
            }}

\begin{document}
\sidepar{\lipsum[2]}% <-- added Spacing from Memoir
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

In case, that somehere you still need original `\sidepar{...}` you now instead it should use `\oldsidepar`. Of course, in definition of `oldsidepar` you can select other name for it ...

Comment: Zarko, your solution works, but I need to define the same line spacing for all the sidenotes in my document (they're about 350, so I need to do it in the preamble).

Comment: @user56153, i managed  to made a solution as you ask in your comment.